# The self intersection class of exceptional divisor of 3-fold blown up along a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Suppose $X$ is a smooth complete variety of dimension $3$, let $\sigma\colon\widetilde{X}\to X$ the blow-up along smooth curve $C\subset X$, let $\sigma^{-1}(C)=E$ be the exceptional divisor, let $f$ be a fiber of the ruled surface $E$. In Iskovskikh-Prokhorov Algebraic Geometry V III. § 2.3., there was formula $$E^2=-\sigma^*C+\deg N_{C/X}\cdot f,$$ and $$E\cdot\sigma^*D=0.$$ (The statements were said to be according to Griffith Harris Principle of algebraic geometry, I couldn't find where,could anyone provide the citation?)

How does one prove these formulas with notations in Fulton's intersection theory? What is the $1$-cycle the $\sigma^*C$ in $A_1(E)$?(Which is defined for l.c.i morphism to be flat pullback followed by Gysin map) Using self-intersection formula we know $E\cdot E\colon=i^!E=c_1(N_{E/X})\cdot E=c_1(O_{E}(-1))\cdot E\in A_1(E)$.

Comment: You'll find everything you need (and more) in §15.4 of Fulton, "blowing up Chern classes".

Comment: You are right, we can calculate with excess intersection formula.